# How to add checkListbox checked items to listbox from sql table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, checklistbox

I have a `checkListBox` that checks items from the column and if it's true, I want to add items from my SQL column into a `listBox` but it adds all the value from the column into my `listBox`

This is my table:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
private void checkListService_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
   var con = new DBConnection();
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM price", con.Connection);
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   da.Fill(ds, "service");

   List<string> services = new List<string>();
   foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables["service"].Rows)
   {
       listBPrice.Items.Add(row["price"].ToString());
   }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

I want it to have the single value which matches the checked items.

Comment: Could you explain the whole process in different way? i.e `User checks a checkListBox item and then ...`

Comment: @GabrielCostin user checks a checklistbox and then find the checkitem from the table and get the price value for it

Comment: So in the left you have the CheckBoxList items and when user checks a listbox you want to get the right price for it?

Comment: @GabrielCostin yes! :)

Comment: But then your problem is that SQL query is wrong. As it is now you get all prices no matter what, so add like `Select * from price WHERE ItemName = itemname`

Answer (score 1):

That is because you never filter the SQL query to give you the price of the selected services.

Assuming you have a Price class that models your Prica table from the database, try the code below:

```
private void checkListService_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    CheckedListBox box = sender as CheckedListBox;

        if (box != null)
        {
            var con = new DBConnection();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM price", con.Connection);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "service");

            var checkedItems = box.SelectedItems;

            var rows = ds.Tables["service"].Rows.AsQueryable().Cast<price>().ToList();

            foreach (var checkedItem in checkedItems)
            {
                var rowsForCheckedItem = rows.Where(x => x.service == ((price)checkedItem).service);

                foreach (var row in rowsForCheckedItem)
                {
                    listBPrice.Items.Add(row.price);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi can I have an example of the price class? Sorry I am not familiar with these codes. Thank you very much!

Comment: public class price
    {
        public int priceId { get; set; }
        public string service { get; set; }
        public System.Int64 price { get; set; }
    }

Comment: I don't have the whole context, I gave an answer based on the information I had. I am not sure this line even works: var rows = ds.Tables["service"].Rows.AsQueryable().Cast<price>().ToList();

Comment: Thank you but yes the `var rows = ds.Tables["service"].Rows.AsQueryable().Cast<price>().ToList();` gave an `System.ArgumentException: 'source is not IEnumerable<>'`

Comment: @vicserna1997, why not try to get the rows from the table directly in a List<price>, and bind the datasource of checkedlistBox with that?

Comment: sir as much as I would want to but I'm really not familiar with this. Just searching online then asking here at stackoverflow. Can you help me? Really appreciate it

Comment: only connecting with teamviewer, or something like that. or maybe using visual studio live share extension.